# How to connect to SQL Server database from another pc or on vmware

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, vmware-workstation

I have developed a simple C# program in Visual Studio 2010 which has a    database which is on my PC, everything is working fine.

But now I want to put this database on another PC or say on vmware, then I want to connect to it from my PC.

How could I achieve this please explain

Comment: change the connection string in your config....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do there are 2 step to follow:

1) Configure the network options in VMware: [Documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net.html) - [Tutorial](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vmware-server-workstation-player-articles/understanding-virtual-networking-vmware-workstation-9.html)

2) Change your connection string accordingly: Here is a [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) if you need help